# How do disable date interval in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I have a problem that in documentation for `FullCalendar` there is nothing about disabling interval dates. I have got a json object with interval dates which have to be disabled

[image]

So, how can I disable this dates?
Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this example on Background Events](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.0/demos/background-events.html) and the [docs page for Background Events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/). Below is the code from the example.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2016-06-12',
    businessHours: true, // display business hours
    editable: true,
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Business Lunch',
            start: '2016-06-03T13:00:00',
            constraint: 'businessHours'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2016-06-13T11:00:00',
            constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
            color: '#257e4a'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2016-06-18',
            end: '2016-06-20'
        },
        {
            title: 'Party',
            start: '2016-06-29T20:00:00'
        },

        // areas where "Meeting" must be dropped
        {
            id: 'availableForMeeting',
            start: '2016-06-11T10:00:00',
            end: '2016-06-11T16:00:00',
            rendering: 'background'
        },
        {
            id: 'availableForMeeting',
            start: '2016-06-13T10:00:00',
            end: '2016-06-13T16:00:00',
            rendering: 'background'
        },

        // red areas where no events can be dropped
        {
            start: '2016-06-24',
            end: '2016-06-28',
            overlap: false,
            rendering: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
        },
        {
            start: '2016-06-06',
            end: '2016-06-08',
            overlap: false,
            rendering: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
        }
    ]
});
```

You can see the background events allow you to have a different colour area where you can set `overlap` property to `false` and then events cannot be placed there.

Comment: Thank you) You helped me a lot